# Serial Instruction bit not clear

Tags: c, arduino, bit-shift, spi, atmega

I've bought a cheap Wingstar 144x32 LCD, because it would be nice to have it plugged onto my NodeMCU for showing some information.

What I *wasn't* expecting, was that nowhere on the internet could I find a working library for that LCD. So I thought I'd write my own.

I spent several hours reading through the [datasheet](https://img.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/381288_2815202.pdf), trying to figure out how the SPI instructions were passed to the LCD. I then discovered that on some other [site](https://www.crystalfontz.com/product/cfag14432dtfhtt-display-module-lcd-144x32) there was an example code for the Arduino (which is faaar too long to understand properly) and one for the ATMega, which is short and way easier to understand.

I opened the files and saw that the interfacing is quite "simple", if I can say so. It looks like this:

```
write_command(0x38); // function set -- 8 bit mode, basic instruction set
write_command(0x0F); // display control -- cursor on, blinking
write_command(0x01); // display clear
write_command(0x06); // entry mode -- cursor moves right, address counter increased by 1
```

`write_command` isn't that important to mention here, because it only sends the command through SPI:

```
void write_command(unsigned char command) {
  SPI_WriteByte(0xF8); // send command header
  SPI_WriteByte(command&0xF0); // send high nibble
  _delay_us(250);
  SPI_WriteByte((command<<4)&0xF0); // send low nibble
  _delay_us(750);
}
```

Despite not understanding what the `&0xF0` or the `<<4)&0xF0` do, I moved on.

I picked randomly the "function set" instruction and [converted it](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-binary-converter) to binary text to see if it's doing that what I'm thinking.

```
0x38 = 0000 0000 0011 1000
```

Excluding the first 8 characters (It wouldn't make sense with those), I'm left with `00111000`, which would make sense putting it there:

[image]

Because: **DL=1** (8bit interface selected, like the comment in the code for the ATMega - great) and **RE=0** (Basic instruction, like in the comment in the code for the ATMega - great!).

But now the real question: What are those "X" in the instruction codes? I already searched the entire datasheet and found nothing about those "X"-es. Why are they inconsistent? What are they supposed to be doing there?

I hope I didn't mess it up too bad.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: They are 'don't care' bits.  On read, they contain no useful information.  On write, they do nothing.

Comment: @MartinJames This means I can set those bits 1 or 0 "of my taste" as they are useless in that current instruction?

Comment: Yes, and on read, just ignore their values.

Comment: @MartinJames Thank you. I'll try it out monday morning when I'm in front of those things again. But, a last 'question': Can you give me a clue what `((command<<4)&0xF0)` does?

Comment: Have you tried reading a C tutorial?

Comment: If a particular bit must ALWAYS be set to 0, or 1, there will be explicit instructions to that effect, eg instead or 0, 1, or X, there will be a [note 1] with appropriate text as a footnote, eg [Note 1; this bit must always be set high].

Comment: As for the bitwise, boolean operations like '((command<<4)&0xF0)', you must do as@melpomene suggests.  You will have to become familiar with those operations, and it's outside the scope of SO to teach them.

Comment: @MartinJames I'll look into those operators later then. Thank you again for your attention and help. If you want, you can answer the question, so I can accept it. It's not a long answer, but it's the right, I suppose.

Comment: Oh........ OK:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are 'don't care' bits. On read, they contain no useful information. On write, they do nothing.